# SoapServer::SoapServer() - SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Tags: php, soap, soapserver

Is there any way to create PHP SoapServer with local secure WSDL URL using self-signed SSL certificate? Following code:

```
$soapServer = new SoapServer("https://mysite.local/my-document?wsdl");
```

throws always exception:

> SoapServer::SoapServer(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
>   Error messages:  error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>   (/var/www/app/modules/generators/components/WsSoap.php:110)

I could not find anything on how to turn off SSL validation for SoapServer. 
Most of issues are related to SoapClient, which is not the case. 
I also want to avoid installing any ca.pem local files with valid certificates, because it would be difficult on many servers, just need to create SoapServer for one-time unit testing, don't care about valid/invalid local domain. Using PHP 7.0.19. Thank you.